# Does a Husband have absolute onwership over his wife ? Does Husband never incur any sin for anything he does to his wife?

Tags: marriage

Do Husbands have absolute onwership over their wives ? (Yudhistira betted Draupdi)

Do Husband never incur any sin for anything he does to his wife ? (Yudhistira was never considered as sinful for putting his wife in a dangerous position of humiliation)

Comment: May be you are in the wrong religious forum.